# iBeacon Accuracy While Android Device In Motion

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am testing out a positioning system using iBeacon and Altbeacon. I have found that my triangulation results are actually pretty accurate, but sometimes it takes upwards of 5 seconds to see the proper results.

For example, say I am currently standing at **Point A**. Altbeacon + my triangulation has me properly placed very close to **Point A**. However, when I move 5 meters away to **Point B**, I remain around **Point A** for around 6 seconds and all of the sudden I snap into place right near **Point B**. Is this an issue with Altbeacon, or possibly the communication between my iBeacons and my Android tablet?

*Note: I am using a Kindle Fire 10, running FireOS 5.1.1 on top of Android. The Bluetooth iBeacon technology is BLE, and broadcasts at around 1Hz.*

Comment: It will never work since the Nature of bluetooth I have work with it and Made what you are trying to reach as university project

Comment: If you need more detailed answer let me know

Comment: A more detailed answer would be great, thanks.

Comment: OK I will do it tomorrow it is night in my location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of time lag that you describe may be caused by averaging intervals on the signal measurement.  You do not say what scanning framework you are using, or if you are using raw RSSI or a distance estimate as input to your algorithm.  The [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) by default uses a 20 second averaging interval (configurable) for its distance estimates.  Other framework's use similar averaging.

Reducing the averaging interval will lessen the lag, but increase the noise as an input to your algorithm.

**EDIT:** To reduce the distance estimate sampling interval to 3 seconds from the default 20 seconds, call:

```
RunningAverageRssiFilter.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(3000l);
```

Comment: I am using the distance estimate from `android-beacon-library` as an input to the algorithm, and my algorithm actually does averaging so perhaps it is a better idea to use raw RSSI? Or if I don't want to change the algorithm inputs, how can I drop that averaging interval down to something much smaller (say 3 seconds)?

Comment: I am using all `BeaconManager` default configurations (besides specifying my iBeacon layout), and getting each `Beacon` distance via `beacon.getDistance()`.

Comment: @davidgyoung a side comment: great to know you are one of the altbeacon developer, my pleasure, I have worked on it on all my projects, as you can see in my answer a link to visual impaired project it uses altbeacon as well.

Comment: @jack-ryan, see my edit with instructions on reducing the sampling interval.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung, I will give the testing a run with a shorter sampling interval and hope for some latency improvements.

Comment: @davidgyoung, we reduced the `sampleExpirationMillseconds` to `1000l`, and surprisingly there is still quite a bit of latency while moving. Is there another reason you could think of for this issue? I am observing upwards of 5 seconds before the location adjusts when in motion.

Comment: I would log the raw distance estimates from each beacon and plot them over time.  Do they have this same lag?

Comment: We ended up doing filtering on the server side and just sending up the raw RSSI's from the Android, and this has tremendously improved latency (though at a small loss of accuracy).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried previously what you were trying to do. There was a lot of issues making it impossible to get correct triangulation results.
Theoretically it should work, but

1. Practically you will have a lot of challenges, like the fact the Bluetooth Beacon uses the 2.4GHz frequency, almost all Bluetooth Beacon has non-directional antenna, which means that you might risk not measuring the signal source but the reflection of the signal surrounded by the beacon.
2. The other fact is the noise from other sources or Bluetooth Beacon in your environment.
3. Depending on the Android phone model, the receiver antenna of Bluetooth is not necessarily mount same place in the phone, that means how you hold the phone will change the RSSI reading
4. Holding the phone in hand or near human body might also give different readings or no reading at all, since the human body contains water that is a signal reducer/killer for Bluetooth signal.

So even thus you improve your latency time of Bluetooth Beacon by software, you will still have these challenge make it almost impossible to get the right results.

I have seen a new directional Bluetooth Beacon I have not testing it yet, but it sounds like it solving some the mentioned issues.

It is correct what @davidgyoung wrote, but that won’t change the fact of real world scenario.

Btw, I have worked with Altbeacon a very nice and respected tool, and I used both RSSI and distance estimate with different type of Bluetooth Beacon and different phones and it did not help much, it is not Altbeacon the problem.

And regarding the university [project](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/guidebelt-maytham-fahmi?trk=prof-post) I mentioned in my comments, we ended up using Bluetooth Beacon in different way to help us finding directions to target for visually impaired people, and we have developed scientific paper on it.

Finally for inspiration of what you are doing and what I mentioned in my answer, see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMWEl6GBGqk) it shows triangulation experiment, the provider of this video is btw also a user at Stackoverflow.

**Note:** my answer here is focusing on the context of triangulation and the challenges here make it as not a sweet solution.

Comment: Great points on sources of inconsistencies in BLE signal measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I believe point #3 is probably related to one of the biggest issues, and #2 as well given the density of beacons in the testing area.

Comment: @JackRyan you are indeed welcome, this was perhaps what we have had of observation from our experiment. And I really hope you get some better results than ours, I would really much like to hear from you when you get more progress with it and your reflection on it.